# How to correctly configure the display of track time in MPNowPlayingInfoCenter

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I created MPNowPlayingInfoCenter and pass the current track time and total track time into it.
But such a problem arises. If I pause the track in MPNowPlayingInfoCenter, wait for a while, and then press play, then I will see that the current time has changed, although it should have remained in the same place because the track was not playing. How to get around this?

```
...
func setupNotificationView(...) {
        nowPlayingInfo = [String : Any]()
        ...
 
        nowPlayingInfo?[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = track.duration
        nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = player.currentTime().seconds
        nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = player.rate
        
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
    }
...
func setupMediaPlayerNotificationView() {
        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
        
        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
            if self.player.rate == 0.0 {
                self.player.play()
                return .success
            }
            return .commandFailed
        }
        
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
            if self.player.rate == 1.0 {
                self.player.pause()
                return .success
            }
            return .commandFailed
        }
        ...
}
```

Comment: Example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/bbaddda65d5461828e55721dfbd6b0f0f6bf1072/bk2ch14p653backgroundPlayerAndInterrupter/backgroundPlayer/backgroundPlayer/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 1):

I am able to stop the current time from changing by setting the MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate value to zero with a literal constant when I pause the track, as shown below:

```
nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = NSNumber(floatLiteral: 0.0)
```